# cordova.js not available while running in chrome

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, ionic2

I created an app using ionic-cli and is trying to run the app. I get below warning in chrome (trying to add infinite-schroll to the gallary app)

> Native: tried calling Splashscreen.hide, but Cordova is not available.
>   Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

How do I include `cordova.js` only during chrome testing

Comment: You don't. Cordova is only for running in devices.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Cordova is only included once your app is built to be run on a device, and so it's not available while testing in a browser. This of course means that plugins relying on Cordova wont work either. That's a limitation of testing in a browser. You can disregard the error.

To test all functionality you should test in an emulator or a real device.

Comment: I use capacitor, not cordova and have same error.

Comment: This answer is wrong, a lot of the functionality can be simulated correctly by cordova by using the "browser" argument, as in `npx ionic cordova run browser --livereload`

Answer (score 3):

use command *ionic cordova run browser* instead of *ionic serve*

Comment: Can you help us understand why the above command will fix the issue?

Comment: I use capacitor, not cordova and have same error.

Comment: What worked for me was `npx ionic cordova run browser --livereload`

Answer (score 1):

Do the following steps:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

then

```
npm i -g native-run
```

then

```
ionic cordova run browser
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

no need to add browser platform you can test it using
ionic cordova run android -l
it will open your emulator and will show messages in consol of browser